# Merge tag [knexjs] into [knex.js]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I came across an obvious duplicate which should be merged.  [knex.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knex.js) is the primary tag with 1905 questions and [knexjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knexjs) is a copy with only 32 questions.

Comment: I wonder why would anyone disagree with the merge proposal given the tags are *identical*? Off-note: wiki and excerpt both need some love (excerpt lacks usage guidance, wiki is ok, but would benefit from more detailed info)

Comment: we are talking about 39 questions. is a merge really necessary, why not as synonym

Comment: @nbk I didn't know there was a difference between a merge and a synonym.  What is the process here?  If there's a small number of questions do we just manually retag them?

Comment: @LindaPaiste - technically, there is - merge destroys the other tag. With such a small number of tags, we can retag manually indeed (and after 24h of no questions the removed one will self-destroy). Not sure a synonym is warranted here as nbk suggests - we can't create synonyms for every typo out there, and Knex is called "knex.js"

Comment: you click on the knex.js tag and you see on the tight sight in the upper region synonyms, but you need at leat 2 - 5 .upvotes. So i hope that a mod or with even more rep can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Merged [knex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knex) and [knexjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knexjs) into [knex.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knex.js)